# UICollectionViewCell reuse

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

There is any code like this one that work with UICollectionViewCell when the method reuse ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    NSString *CellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellId%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];

    if (!cell) 
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is to *reuse* cells, that's why the reuse identifier should be the same for all cells, at least all cells of one class (that's why it makes sense to declare `CellId` as a static variable - this method will be called a lot). `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method returns cell ready to be reused, if any. If there is no such cell you should create it and later, when it is no longer visible `UICollectoinView` will add it into "reusable cells pool" and return for `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {

    static NSString *CellId = @"YourCellIdentifier";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The OP asks about UICollectionView, not UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a similar method for collectionview as shown below:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"collectionCell";

    collectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
UICollectionReusableView *collView = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You can find the info in the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: